# Centerfixing Elements Across All Devices (One CSS file)

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile

I have a page that displays a user's username upon logging in like so: http://jsfiddle.net/cagxvL9x/2

It works up to the point where the user's screen height is less than the width. (E.g. tablets and Desktop/Laptop/Netbook Computer systems),

I know I could use a PHP detection method and write separate CSS files for each detection, but I'd prefer to keep it in one file, nice and tidy. (And I'd prefer not to manipulate element.style with Javascript).

I managed this before, but then on Notepad++ I acidently forgot to backup that file and overwrote it without knowing with a new file. (Stupid move on my part).

Can someone help me make the three boxes (incl. their overlays) stay in the center of the screen for all device layouts, I can't seem to recreate the way I did it before, and nor can I recover the old file.

Thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<html>
   <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0,  maximum-scale=1.0">
   </head>
   <body>
       <div class="content">
           <div class="kon">
               <div class="ajx">
                    <article class="grt">
                    <div class="grtin">Welcome, (username)</div>
                    <div class="appoverlay">
                        <div class="apps">
                            <div class="oleybar">
                                <div class="aoley oley"></div>
                                <div class="vpoley oley"></div>
                                <div class="foley oley"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="1">
                                <div class="bg"></div>
                                <div class="anchor"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="2">
                                <div class="bg"></div>
                                <div class="anchor"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="3">
                                <div class="bg"></div>
                                <div class="anchor"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                 </article>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgb(37, 63, 35);
}

.kon,
.ajx{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.grt{
    opacity: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000;
    transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    text-align: center;
}

.appear{
    opacity: 1 !important;
    display: block !important;
    visibility: visible !important;
}

.slip{
    top: 45%;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out 1s;
}

.slip.grt{
    margin-top: 25%;
}

.1,
.2,
.3{
    height: 44px;
    width: 44px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

.bg{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: rgb(32, 57, 30);
}

.apps{

}

.appoverlay{
    text-align: center;
    width: 52%;
    position: absolute;
}

.oleybar{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.oley{
    height: 31px;
    width: 31px;
    background-size: 31px 31px !important;
    border-radius: 40px;
    float: left;
    background: #fff;
}

.aoley.oley{
    background: #fff;
}

.vpoley.oley{
    background: #2e3;
}

.foley.oley{
    background: #999;
}
```

jQuery (JS):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".grt").addClass("appear slip");
    $app(".1, .aoley", function(){
        $(".grt").removeClass("appear slip");
        setTimeout(function(){$(".kon").empty().load("../../1/index.php .ajx");}, 1400);
    });
    $app(".2, .vpoley", function(){
        $(".grt").removeClass("appear slip");
        setTimeout(function(){$(".kon").empty().load("../../2/index.php .ajx");}, 1400);
    });
    $app(".3, .foley", function(){
        $(".grt").removeClass("appear slip");
        setTimeout(function(){$(".kon").empty().load("../../3/index.php .ajx");}, 1400);
    });
});

function $app(s, f){
    $(s).click(f);
}
```

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/cagxvL9x/3/ I've added a background for you to see that the size of the element does not match the content size, you'd better take care of that before trying to center it. If I targetted the wrong element, please provide more information :)

Comment: Alright, thanks. I'll get back to you.